# StreamInsight Event Cache Configuration

Tags: caching, streaminsight

We are making some tests with StreamInsight and we are wondering if there is something like event information cache and if it is configurable.

Thanks in advance.

Bruno

Answer (score 1):

There is no caching that you can control. But rather than asking about a specific "feature", can you describe what you are trying to accomplish? It's very possible that you can do what you think you need a cache for using temporal properties.